# Appium : UiAutomator quit before it successfully launched

Tags: appium

> Launching Appium server with command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node.exe lib\server\main.js --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4723 --platform-name Android --platform-version 23 --automation-name Appium --log-no-color
>   info: Welcome to Appium v1.4.16 (REV ae6877eff263066b26328d457bd285c0cc62430d)
>   info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:4723
>   info: [debug] Non-default server args: {"address":"127.0.0.1","logNoColors":true,"platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"23","automationName":"Appium"}
>   info: Console LogLevel: debug
>   info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"appPackage":"com.Honkampkrueger.hk","appActivity":".MainActivity","app":"C:\Users\kuldeep.sahu\workspace\AppiumIntro\Src\honkamp.apk","browserName":"","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"Android Emulator","version":"4.4.2"}}
>   info: Client User-Agent string: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.1 (Java/1.8.0_71)
>   info: [debug] The following desired capabilities were provided, but not recognized by appium. They will be passed on to any other services running on this server. : version
>   info: [debug] Using local app from desired caps: C:\Users\kuldeep.sahu\workspace\AppiumIntro\Src\honkamp.apk
>   info: [debug] Creating new appium session f2eb01fe-7b8c-4e7c-89c6-5d776471a569
>   info: Starting android appium
>   info: [debug] Getting Java version
>   info: Java version is: 1.8.0_71
>   info: [debug] Checking whether adb is present
>   info: [debug] Using adb from C:\Program Files\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe
>   info: [debug] Using fast reset? true
>   info: [debug] Preparing device for session
>   info: [debug] Checking whether app is actually present
>   info: Retrieving device
>   info: [debug] Trying to find a connected android device
>   info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices
>   info: [debug] 1 device(s) connected
>   info: Found device emulator-5554
>   info: [debug] Setting device id to emulator-5554
>   info: [debug] Waiting for device to be ready and to respond to shell commands (timeout = 5)
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 wait-for-device
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 shell "echo 'ready'"
>   info: [debug] Starting logcat capture
>   info: [debug] Getting device API level
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
>   info: [debug] Device is at API Level 19
>   info: Device API level is: 19
>   info: [debug] Extracting strings for language: default
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 shell "getprop persist.sys.language"
>   info: [debug] Current device persist.sys.language: en
>   info: [debug] java -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\jars\appium_apk_tools.jar" "stringsFromApk" "C:\Users\kuldeep.sahu\workspace\AppiumIntro\Src\honkamp.apk" "C:\Users\KULDEE~1.SAH\AppData\Local\Temp\com.Honkampkrueger.hk" en
>   info: [debug] No strings.xml for language 'en', getting default strings.xml
>   info: [debug] java -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\jars\appium_apk_tools.jar" "stringsFromApk" "C:\Users\kuldeep.sahu\workspace\AppiumIntro\Src\honkamp.apk" "C:\Users\KULDEE~1.SAH\AppData\Local\Temp\com.Honkampkrueger.hk"
>   info: [debug] Reading strings from converted strings.json
>   info: [debug] Setting language to default
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 push "C:\Users\KULDEE~1.SAH\AppData\Local\Temp\com.Honkampkrueger.hk\strings.json" /data/local/tmp
>   info: [debug] Checking whether aapt is present
>   info: [debug] Using aapt from C:\Program Files\SDK\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe
>   info: [debug] Retrieving process from manifest.
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files\SDK\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe" dump xmltree C:\Users\kuldeep.sahu\workspace\AppiumIntro\Src\honkamp.apk AndroidManifest.xml
>   info: [debug] Set app process to: com.Honkampkrueger.hk
>   info: [debug] Not uninstalling app since server not started with --full-reset
>   info: [debug] Checking app cert for C:\Users\kuldeep.sahu\workspace\AppiumIntro\Src\honkamp.apk.
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: java -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\jars\verify.jar" C:\Users\kuldeep.sahu\workspace\AppiumIntro\Src\honkamp.apk
>   info: [debug] App already signed.
>   info: [debug] Zip-aligning C:\Users\kuldeep.sahu\workspace\AppiumIntro\Src\honkamp.apk
>   info: [debug] Checking whether zipalign is present
>   info: [debug] Using zipalign from C:\Program Files\SDK\build-tools\23.0.2\zipalign.exe
>   info: [debug] Zip-aligning apk.
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files\SDK\build-tools\23.0.2\zipalign.exe" -f 4 C:\Users\kuldeep.sahu\workspace\AppiumIntro\Src\honkamp.apk C:\Users\KULDEE~1.SAH\AppData\Local\Temp\11615-3480-14zot2k\appium.tmp
>   info: [debug] MD5 for app is 91f72bc7e64a758cdb9d0b8414bd853c
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 shell "ls /data/local/tmp/91f72bc7e64a758cdb9d0b8414bd853c.apk"
>   info: [debug] Getting install status for com.Honkampkrueger.hk
>   info: [debug] Getting device API level
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
>   info: [debug] Device is at API Level 19
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 shell "pm list packages -3 com.Honkampkrueger.hk"
>   info: [debug] App is not installed
>   info: Installing App
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 shell "mkdir -p /data/local/tmp/"
>   info: [debug] Removing any old apks
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 shell "ls /data/local/tmp/*.apk"
>   info: [debug] Found an apk we want to keep at /data/local/tmp/91f72bc7e64a758cdb9d0b8414bd853c.apk
>   info: [debug] Couldn't find any apks to remove
>   info: [debug] Uninstalling com.Honkampkrueger.hk
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 shell "am force-stop com.Honkampkrueger.hk"
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 uninstall com.Honkampkrueger.hk
>   info: [debug] App was not uninstalled, maybe it wasn't on device?
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 shell "pm install -r /data/local/tmp/91f72bc7e64a758cdb9d0b8414bd853c.apk"
>   info: [debug] Forwarding system:4724 to device:4724
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 forward tcp:4724 tcp:4724
>   info: [debug] Pushing appium bootstrap to device...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 push "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\android_bootstrap\AppiumBootstrap.jar" /data/local/tmp/
>   info: [debug] Pushing settings apk to device...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk"
>   info: [debug] Pushing unlock helper app to device...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\unlock_apk\unlock_apk-debug.apk"
>   info: Starting App
>   info: [debug] Attempting to kill all 'uiautomator' processes
>   info: [debug] Getting all processes with 'uiautomator'
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 shell "ps 'uiautomator'"
>   info: [debug] No matching processes found
>   info: [debug] Running bootstrap
>   info: [debug] spawning: C:\Program Files\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell uiautomator runtest AppiumBootstrap.jar -c io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap -e pkg com.Honkampkrueger.hk -e disableAndroidWatchers false
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: shortMsg=java.lang.NullPointerException
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: longMsg=null
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: 0
>   info: [debug] UiAutomator exited
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Program Files\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s emulator-5554 shell "echo 'ping'"
>   info: [debug] Attempting to uninstall app
>   info: [debug] Not uninstalling app since server not started with --full-reset
>   info: [debug] Cleaning up android objects
>   info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
>   error: UiAutomator quit before it successfully launched
>   error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: UiAutomator quit before it successfully launched
>   info: [debug] Error: UiAutomator quit before it successfully launched
>       at [object Object]. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\android.js:205:23)
>       at [object Object]. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\android-hybrid.js:249:5)
>       at Object.async.eachSeries (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:142:20)
>       at [object Object].androidHybrid.stopChromedriverProxies (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\android-hybrid.js:233:9)
>       at [object Object]. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\android.js:200:10)
>       at [object Object]. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\android.js:222:9)
>       at [object Object].androidCommon.uninstallApp (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\android-common.js:478:5)
>       at [object Object]. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\android.js:220:12)
>       at [object Object]. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\android.js:229:11)
>       at C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\adb.js:901:7
>       at [object Object]. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\adb.js:180:9)
>       at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:742:7)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
>       at maybeClose (child_process.js:1016:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1088:5)
>   info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: UiAutomator quit before it successfully launched)","origValue":"UiAutomator quit before it successfully launched"},"sessionId":null}
>   info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 46111.400 ms - 218

Error : Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: UiAutomator quit before it successfully launched) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information).

Anyone have solution of this as My running emulator is very slow to launch.

Comment: seems like every question at your end is incomplete without the `slow to launch` .. you might want to get better hardware configurations to work on in which case.

Answer (score 1):

> UiAutomator quit before it successfully launched error: Failed to
>   start an Appium session, err was: Error: UiAutomator quit before it
>   successfully launched info: [debug] Error: UiAutomator quit before it
>   successfully launched at [object Object]. (C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\devices\android\android.js:205:23)
>   at [object Object].

These suggests that UIAutomator did not launch due to which Appium session was not created. [`SessionNotCreatedException` on your IDE]
Restarting adb server and appium serve shall help you.

Prior to that you can also try running the UIAutomator using shell to verify if its working alright on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

In case you using Appium 1.4 + version to automate android (7.0 / N / Nougat ) version, this issue persists. you have to make couple of changes to get this working properly.

We had a similar issue, when we started to automate a simple mobile application using appium, android studio and selenium webdriver, after so many searches and also looking at various appium support tickets, we found that it was a bug and they have given an alternative to fix and go ahead.

You have to change code in couple of places in following file: 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\adb.js

Those details have been listed in below article: 
http://www.testingtools.co/appium/error-command-failed-adb-exe-s-emulator-5554-shell-ps-uiautomator

Hope it helps you, in case you have any queries, you can post them over the blog article in form of comments as well.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run UIAutomator and Appium server in parallel, this is known issue. Make sure your Appium server is stopped before you run your UIAutomator then try again. This should work.